# Pandas: Panel predictions

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

I have a data frame of the format

```
            county  ones        emplvl
date                                  
2003-01-01    1001     1  10955.000000
2003-04-01    1001     1  11090.333333
2003-07-01    1001     1  11157.000000
2003-10-01    1001     1  11335.666667
2004-01-01    1001     1  11045.000000
2004-04-01    1001     1  11175.666667
2004-07-01    1001     1  11135.666667
2004-10-01    1001     1  11480.333333
2005-01-01    1001     1  11441.000000
2005-04-01    1001     1  11531.000000
2005-07-01    1001     1  11320.000000
2005-10-01    1001     1  11516.666667
2006-01-01    1001     1  11291.000000
2006-04-01    1001     1  11223.000000
2006-07-01    1001     1  11230.000000
2006-10-01    1001     1  11293.000000
2007-01-01    1001     1  11126.666667
2007-04-01    1001     1  11383.666667
2007-07-01    1001     1  11535.666667
2007-10-01    1001     1  11567.333333
2008-01-01    1001     1  11226.666667
2008-04-01    1001     1  11342.000000
2008-07-01    1001     1  11201.666667
2008-10-01    1001     1  11321.000000
2009-01-01    1001     1  11082.333333
2009-04-01    1001     1  11099.000000
2009-07-01    1001     1  10905.666667
2009-10-01    1001     1  10928.333333
2010-01-01    1001     1  10616.000000
2010-04-01    1001     1  10746.333333
2010-07-01    1001     1  10652.333333
2010-10-01    1001     1  10761.000000
2011-01-01    1001     1  10659.000000
2011-04-01    1001     1  10821.000000
2011-07-01    1001     1  10442.666667
2011-10-01    1001     1  10585.333333
2012-01-01    1001     1  10065.333333
2012-04-01    1001     1  10172.666667
2012-07-01    1001     1  10042.000000
2012-10-01    1001     1  10267.666667
```

and I would like to run a regression onto each group (based on values before 2007), and then add predicted values for the whole time period. The code I have right now iterates over each group. As I have hundreds of groups, it takes quite long to run:

```
def predictedValues(group):
    sub = group[group.year < 2007]
    if len(sub) == 0:
        return None
    regression = sm.OLS(sub.emplvl, sub[['ones', 'quarter_index']], hasconst=True).fit()
    result = regression.predict(group[['ones', 'quarter_index']])
    result = pd.DataFrame(data=result, columns=['predicted'], index=group.index)
    return result

result = df.groupby(['county']).apply(predictedValues)
```

What is a more efficient way to do this? I'd prefer `statsmodels` over `pandas`, as `pandas.ols` is deprecated.

#### A little more efficient

The following runs through quite quickly, but it's atypical `pandas` code. So I'm still happy for improvements:

```
for county in df.county.unique():
    group = df.loc[df.county == county]
    df.loc[df.county == county, 'predicted'] = predictedValues(group)
```

Comment: 15 minutes later, the code is still running.

Comment: I don't see what would take a lot of time here. A few hundred linear regression should be fast. One thing to check: Are your ['ones', 'quarter_index'] columns both float (float64)?  It's usually necessary to check that unnecessary copying and conversions are avoided inside loops.

Comment: @user333700 See my update. Appears that - for some reason - `groups.apply()` is carrying too much overhead.

Comment: I'm not an expert in pandas overhead. groupby().apply won't be able to do better than the simple loop, but I don't know why it would be much slower.

Comment: I think use `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` is faster than `sm.OLS`.